# Fortify Exclusion File Location

Tags: maven, fortify

Ok, so I'm trying to get exclusions to work with fortify scanning using maven. I've got everything working except for the exclusions. The documentation says to create a *.exclusions file and add com.fortify.sca.exclude="fileA;fileB;fileC" to the file. However, it does not say where to put the file. Do I put it in the maven directory? Or do I put it in the Fortify directory? Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, my reputation isn't high enough yet for me to ask you what version of Fortify SCA you're using, so that I can try and better help you. But I'll try taking a stab with this.

I'm not sure about the *.exclusions file you're talking about, but perhaps you can add something on the command line when you call maven to build and scan your app using the "-Dfortify.sca.exclude" property option. See the example command below:

```
mvn com.fortify.sca.plugins.maven:sca-maven-plugin: <ver> :translate -Dfortify.sca.source.version=1.8 -Dfortify.sca.exclude="fileA;fileB;fileC;
```

Comment: Yes I've seen this syntax as well, but I unfortunately have over 400 unique directories I need to exclude. Below is what I'm referencing in Appendix F of the User Documentation:

Comment: Excluding Files from the Scan
If you don’t want to include all of the files in your project or solution, you can direct SCA to exclude selected files from your scan:
1. Create an exclusion file in a text editor.
2. Add the following line to the file you just created:
   com.fortify.sca.exclude="fileA;fileB;fileC"

3. Add the following code to the translation step:
   -Dfortify.sca.properties.file=my.exclusions

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution, I got a question. does "fileA;fileB;fileC" needs to be file paths from the root folder of the project or just file names?